# Java related error met when installing COMSOL

Tags: rhel, java

I would like to install a software called COMSOL on Redhat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)) cluster. COMSOL is designed as a Windows software, and its installation requires X window call-out from linux command.

After mounting the installation file, command

```
sh setup
```

is supposed to call out the X window for installation. However, I'm having Java related errors running the above command. The error messages are at the end of this post as they take too much space. Do you have any suggestions for me to deal with this? Thanks a lot!

error messages:

```
Extracting temporary COMSOL installer components in /tmp...

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "TRUE" of type `gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property `visible' of type `gboolean'

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings: assertion `GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid icon size 6


(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'gtk-dialog-error' for stock:

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings: assertion `GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-WARNING **: gtkstyle.c:2318: invalid icon size '6'

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_render_icon: assertion `pixbuf != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_attributes: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_wrap: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_screen_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_screen_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:32180): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_line_count: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x00002b0a223cbe88, pid=32180, tid=47322072959904
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x13be88]  gtk_label_get_angle+0x428
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid32180.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
Removing temporary COMSOL installer components...
```

Comment: Our cluster supporter helped solve the problem. Actually it is simple, even stupid. I was using MobaXterm terminal software, which could call out X wiindows from clusters I used previously. However this time it fails to call out the X window from our cluster. After changing to Xmanager, it is straightforward to get the graphical window and finish the installation.